# How can I make a regular expression move to the next match?

Tags: regex, c++14, std

I'm trying to use a regular expression to find matches in text of the following pattern:

```
(500,0,'ABC',4),(550,0,'ABC',0),(450,0,'D\'E,F',0),(650,0,'G_HI',0);
```

What I want is the **first number** and the **string**, but *only* if the second and fourth positions (always numbers) are both zero. In this example, this would result in these matches:

```
550    ABC
450    D\'E,F
650    G_HI
```

The regex I came up with is `\((\d+),0,'(\S+?)',0` but when it finds the `4)`, it keeps consuming text until it reaches the first `0)`. I want it to skip this match, and try the next one.

Is this possible with regular expressions?

I'm using C++14 std::regex, which to my understanding has fairly good support for several dialects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your regex from `\((\d+),0,'(\S+?)',0` to `\((\d+),0,'(([^']|\\')+)',0`. This allows the string to contain any combination of non-`'` characters or the string `\'`. It matches your requirements.

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uX4lM7/1)

Comment: Thank you, not only does it work, it's even better than `\S`. Is the inner pair of parentheses there so that the `+` can encompass both `^'` and `\'`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Glad to help!